# How to add "join group" button on facebook?

Tags: facebook

In my website, I would like to add "join group" button for my facebook group.
I know this is possible to do with "Like", but can't find a way to add a button for joining a facebook group.

Is it possible? Am I missing anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Facebook doesn't offer that.

You can set buttons to like/follow a page but not a group. A Walk-around is to create a page and direct via details and posts to join the group. I've seen it done for 100K+ user groups.

Get technical info for these directly from facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/follow-button

Comment: thanks! let me get it right: do you mean making a page (and put a like button to a page within my website) and within the page convince people joining the group?

Comment: Yes. Facebook does not see the value in promoting groups as-is but has many options, both paid and free, to promote pages. Once people like the service you offer in your page they will seek to join the group where the service is offered or you can use marketing tactics to make them join the group.

Comment: thanks @Poyke (+1)! sorry for the dummy question , but what tactics can you think of except saying "please join our group XYZ"?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that **every facebook group** has a **unique url** you can link to. (`facebook.com/groups/123456789etc/`)

What I have seen several times is that websites have a button "join group" that links to that url. The user still has to join or request to join from there.

I know this isn't a code related answer, but there wasn't a marketing related stackexchange site the last time I checked.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Open the group page and choose Embed Invite.**

[image: Facebook Group Join Widget]

A window appears with the code to add to your message.

**2. Copy the Code to your website.**

You can find more information [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/group-plugin/?locale=en_US) :